# How to use Laravel Eloquent to query a minimum number of related models using groupBy and havingRaw

Tags: php, laravel, count, eloquent, having

I want to select a `user` only if they have more than 10 trips, where the `trip` must have a walking `leg`.

**Table structure**

```
// users
(int) id

// trips
(int) id
(fk) user_id

// legs
(int) id
(fk) trip_id
(str) mode
```

**Models**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function trips()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Trip::class);
    }
}

class Trip extends Model
{
    public function legs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Leg::class);
    }
}
```

I can return a user that has trips where there is a walking leg ...

```
$user = User::where('id', '=', 1)
    ->whereHas('trips', function($query) {
        ->query('legs', function($query) {
            $query->whereHas('mode', '=', 'walking');
        });
    })
    ->first();
```

... and it seems that it [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976241/implementing-group-by-and-having-in-laravel-using-eloquent) [be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39593755/eloquent-havingraw-problems) [done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240420/building-sql-query-in-eloquent/39240459#39240459) using `groupBy()` and `havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 10')` ...

```
$query = User::whereHas('trips', function ($query) {
    $query
        ->whereHas('legs', function ($query) {
            $query->where('mode', '=', 'walking');
        })
        ->groupBy('id')
        ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 10');
});
```

... but this is where I'm stuck.

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can't see a `mode_id` column?

Comment: Fixed the examples. They're dumbed down a bit for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)
    ->whereHas('trips', function($query) {
        $query->whereHas('legs', function ($query) {
            $query->where('mode', 'walking');
        });
    }, '>', 10)
    ->first();
```

`whereHas` works just like `has` with a closure for conditions.

```
public function whereHas($relation, Closure $callback = null, $operator = '>=', $count = 1);
```

Comment: Knew it would be simple. Thanks!